# AWS IoT +multiple environments (dev/qa/uat/prod)

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

## Background:

Our team only has one AWS root account (several IAM users);

We have multiple environments (dev/qa/uat/prod) in AWS with S3 (different buckets) & EC2 (different EC2)...;

Everything is going well until we have a new requirement which requires IoT feature;

## Question:

**How to setup multiple environments for AWS IoT?**

I would like to isolate the IoT stuff (such as Thing, Certificates...) for different environments;

If we use a separated root account to setup IoT, we have to move other existing environments (EC2/S3) to the new root account to integrate with the corresponding IoT environment, that is not what we want;

Is it possible for one AWS root account? (and we want in one region);

Comment: You need to use separate AWS accounts for having `dev/qa/uat/prod` stages

Comment: Hi @RahulMane, we append the env name to every IoT resources (thing/topic...);

Comment: It is the similar approach with mlohbihler;

Comment: How did you manage to identify reversed topics? -- Job/Shadow?

Comment: All IoT resources (topics/thing) name will contain a environment name;e.g. a thing name could be "dev-serialxxxxxxxxx", and other resources have similar name pattern;

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this same problem. The only decent solution i came up with was to put my stage name in to the MQTT topic. For example:

`/dev/field-readings/device-1234
/testing/field-readings/device-1234
/production/field-readings/device-1234`

This works for topics that i have defined, but not for predefined topics such as for connect and disconnect.